# Visibility in namespace c# wpf

Tags: c#, mvvm, namespaces, visibility

How should I add a file to project to make him visible in specified namespace?

For example:

I have folder ViewModels in project. When i trying to add some .cs file to that namespace i got error in different part of code in that project `The name "MenuItem" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:P1.ViewModels".`

Should I add some reference to that file to tell program "MainWindow content depends on that MenuItem file" or make MenuItem file specially belongs to that namespace??

Thank you in advance

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;
using P1.Mvvm;

namespace P1.ViewModels
{
    public class MenuItem : BindableBase
    {
        private object _icon;
        private string _text;
        private bool _isEnabled = true;
        private DelegateCommand _command;
        private Uri _navigationDestination;

    public object Icon
    {
        get { return this._icon; }
        set { this.SetProperty(ref this._icon, value); }
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get { return this._text; }
        set { this.SetProperty(ref this._text, value); }
    }

    public bool IsEnabled
    {
        get { return this._isEnabled; }
        set { this.SetProperty(ref this._isEnabled, value); }
    }

    public ICommand Command
    {
        get { return this._command; }
        set { this.SetProperty(ref this._command, (DelegateCommand)value); }
    }

    public Uri NavigationDestination
    {
        get { return this._navigationDestination; }
        set { this.SetProperty(ref this._navigationDestination, value); }
    }

    public bool IsNavigation => this._navigationDestination != null;
}
```

}

Comment: Is the class or property public?

Comment: Class, I having visibility problem in MainWindow xaml trying to set:  DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:MenuItem}"

Comment: is the class created like this public class MenuItem? private class MenuItem or class MenuItem won't show up.  Also make sure any types for properties used in the class are public also.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the code for MenuItem

Comment: Code added even when I click 'go to definition'  it opens MenuItem.. But xaml cant see it in namespace

Comment: Have you built your project?

Comment: Yes build, rebuild i tried a lot of tips found on google but still nothing :/

Comment: How have you specified the DataContext in your MainWindow.xaml? If the MenuItem class is not within this context, it cant be bound.